# findAssocs() of tm packages suppresses associations

Tags: r, tm

I am using `findAssocs()` of the `tm` package on a document frequency matrix to identify words which are associated with particular term(s) across various documents in a corpus.

My problem is that I get different output when giving a  vector of terms as input to the function compared to giving a single term as input.

Here is my example.

```
library(tm)
txt  <- c("alpha bravo", "alpha charlie", "alpha charlie", "zulu")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
dtm  <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

Returns the following dtm

```
> as.matrix(dtm)
    Terms
Docs alpha bravo charlie zulu 
   1     1     1       0    0
   2     1     0       1    0
   3     1     0       1    0
   4     0     0       0    1
```

If I would want to identify all terms associated with `"alpha"` I get the following output (as intended):

```
> findAssocs(dtm, "alpha", 0.00)
$alpha
charlie   bravo 
   0.58    0.33
```

I could do the same for `"bravo"` and get the following output (as intended):

```
> findAssocs(dtm, "bravo", 0.00)
$bravo
alpha
0.33
```

As I would like to find those associations for a number of terms I have passed a vector to `findAssocs` in order to get the required output. However, if I pass a vector of terms (chr) to the function the output is different from the one I get for single inputs:

```
> findAssocs(dtm, c("alpha","bravo"), 0.00)
$alpha
charlie 
   0.58 

$bravo
numeric(0)
```

Actually, the assocation between `"alpha"`and `"bravo"` is omitted which is not the behavior I would have expected here. The function seems to treat the individual terms independently of each other and thus does not analyze the correlation between `"alpha"` and `"bravo"` if they are both passed to the function in a vector.

Can anyone explain that behavior and tell me how to omitt it? As a workaround I could apply the function for each single term but that is not really handy...

**UPDATE**

What I find odd is that the correlation between `"alpha"` and `"bravo"` is not omitted if we plot the associations, e.g. through the following code:

```
> freqTerm <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 1)
> freqTerm
[1] "alpha"   "bravo"   "charlie" "zulu" 

plot(dtm, term=freqTerm, corThreshold=0.0, weighting=T, attrs=list(node=list(fixedsize=FALSE, shape="ellipse")))
```

How is `plot(dtm, term=freqTerm ...` different from `"findAssocs()"`?

Comment: It doesn't work because `findAssocs(dtm, c("alpha", "bravo"), 0.00)` compares the terms `c("alpha", "bravo")` to all the **remaining** terms in the corpus. It does not calculate the pairwise correlations of the terms in the vector you pass in.

Comment: the proper way to do what you want would be `sapply(c("alpha","bravo"), function(x) findAssocs(dtm, x, 0.00))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tm::findAssocs()` omits direct comparisons for exactly the reasons stated in the comment by @Steven Beauport.  Given that you are searching for a small set of terms likely to be highly correlated, this seems more like a bug than a feature.  This is illustrated by the example of this function (see `?tm::findAssocs`) where the terms `oil` and `opec` are the most similar, but this is masked by the omission of each from the other's association vector.

An alternative is to use the equivalent feature from the **quanteda** package:

```
library(quanteda)
txt  <- c("alpha bravo", "alpha charlie", "alpha charlie", "zulu")
corp <- corpus(txt)
dtm  <- dfm(corp, verbose = FALSE)
# this also works fine if you want to go straight from text:
# dtm <- dfm(txt, verbose = FALSE)

(simlist <- similarity(dtm, c("alpha","bravo"), margin = "features"))
## similarity Matrix:
## $alpha
## charlie   bravo    zulu 
##  0.5774  0.3333 -1.0000 
## 
## $bravo
##   alpha    zulu charlie 
##  0.3333 -0.3333 -0.5774
```

Or if you prefer it as a matrix:

```
as.matrix(simlist)
##              alpha      bravo
## alpha    1.0000000  0.3333333
## charlie  0.5773503 -0.5773503
## bravo    0.3333333  1.0000000
## zulu    -1.0000000 -0.3333333
```

`similarity()` can do cosine similarities as well as other similarities defined in the **proxy** package, but the (Pearson's) correlation and cosine methods are currently implemented in fully sparse computation, whereas the others are not (yet).  By defining `margin = "documents"`, furthermore, you can compare documents instead of terms, for instance for clustering.

Comment: Any chance you also know why the plot function works different then (see my Update in the question above)

Comment: It's because the plot method for a dtm object has nothing to do with findAssocs() - instead it is based on the dtm which has the complete matrix of terms.